# Long delay when presenting UIAlert

Tags: swift, delay, loading, uialertcontroller

I'm having a problem with presenting an alert. I'm using UIAlertController. When the user presses the submit button, an alert needs to be presented immediately saying "Please Wait.." while the app does some operations. The alert is dismissed after the operations are complete. I'm having a long delay (several seconds) before the alert is presented even though the alert is supposed to be presented before i even start doing the operations. I tried dispatch async and tried using closures and nothing is working..still a delay of several seconds before alert is presented. 
How do i make it so that the alert is presented immediately after the button the pressed?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    submitButton.addTarget(self,action:#selector(buttonAction),for:.touchUpInside)

}



@objc func buttonAction(){ 

    waiting()

    doOperations()

}

func waiting(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

    alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)

    self.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

}


func doOperations(){
    ...
}

func dismissWaiting{
    ...
    //dismiss alert 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried without adding something to UIAlertControler ? e.g., Remove this line: `alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)`

Comment: why are you write this line:
alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
remove this line.

Comment: yes i tried that...i removed all the loadingindicator code and still had a delay before alert was presented

Comment: Is there some other tasks constantly running on main thread?

Comment: Narrow down for the problematic part, comment `doOperations` function and let the code `waiting` run and see what happen.

Comment: NeverHopeless: yes  I commented out doOperations() and there was no delay....so doOperations() is what is  somehow causing the delay. without DispatchQueue.main.async, all the code in waiting() gets runs before the code in doOperations...with DispathQueue.main.async the code in doOperations gets run before the code in waiting. i verified this just using print statements. in both cases i get the same delay in the presentation of the the alert. Ricky Mo: I'm not sure how to check but there shouldn't be. i'll do some reading on how to check

Answer (score 0):

Just dispatch to main thread the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I resolved the problem just by putting the call to `doOperations` in the completion of the presentation of the alert. Like this:

`self.present(alert, animated: false, completion: {self.doOperations()})`

Now the alert is presented instantly after button press and everything works fine. Thanks guys for all the suggestions.